# Should I use capital or small letter here? "Dear All" or "Dear all"?

Tags: capitalization

"Dear team"/ "Dear all"/ "Dear colleagues"
Since I don't use a name after dear, I don't need to use Capital letter. is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, "all" is a noun.  It is a specific noun, so it is called a proper noun.  Proper nouns are capitalized.  This applies for "team," "colleague," "employees" or anything else, such as "Dear Costco Sales Team," or "Dear Apollo 11 Crew,"

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Can "Dear All" be considered to be more polite than "Dear all"?  I have searched some business email writing samples and found some use "All" and some don't.

Comment: @Wang  You asked about capitalization, so I answered that.  I don't know to whom you are writing, so I can't say whether "Dear All," is polite or not.  The capitalization does not make it polite or impolite.  If I were writing this, and sending it to my colleagues, I would write "Dear Colleagues,"  I do not like "DearAll," and prefer to address the people receiving the email; "Dear Cisco Employees / Sales Team / 2015 Award Winers," etc.

Comment: "All" is definitely not a noun. In any case, it can be a pronoun.