# What kind of phrase is "Dear (recipient name)?

Tags: grammar

I posted this question [In "Dear X" what function does "X" serve?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/274847/129806) and realized that I didn't express the question properly.  This is my meaning:

One can start a letter with Dear Jane, Dear Mr Jobs: or Dear Bob

Why is it that the expression Dear (person's name) can take either a comma, colon, or nothing and still be acceptable?  What kind of phrase is Dear (person's name) that makes it open to such varied interpretation and use?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603546/2085).

Answer (score 1):

In the US, there is a long-standing convention that colons end the salutation in a business letter and commas end them in a personal letter.  From the 1910 *[Style-book of Business English, Designed for Use in Business Colleges, High Schools, and for Self-instruction](https://books.google.com/books?id=xDkuAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22business%20composition%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* by H. W. Hammond, we find the following instruction for punctuating a business letter:

> The explanation to give in connection with punctuating the salutation
>   is that there can be only one form employed, and that is the **colon**.

I found an amusing set of letters to the editor of *T[he Phonographic Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=_HYrAAAAYAAJ&dq=colon%20formality&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* from 1899 explaining the use of the colon in business letters based on the mark's formality and the dictates of the pedagogy of the day.  The *Magazine* was a publication of The Phonographic Institute, a school in Cincinnati, Ohio for teaching shorthand.

Comment: Well, I can kind of understand the punctuation with a comma, as in "Dear Bob, I hope this letter reaches you." Dear Bob being a subordinate phrase (?) that can be put at the end, "I hope this letter reaches you dear bob."  But I can't think of this with a colon.  Colons are for lists and clauses that further explain or clarify.  Did the colon have another use that fell out of fashion?

Comment: Thanks for taking this question seriously.  As you can see I don;t accept "because that's the way we do it," for answers.  There's always a reason for why things happen.

Comment: Latin has a vocative case, which is why it's "Et tu, Brute?" and not "Et tu, Brutus?"  But English needs a punctuation mark to set off a vocative.  Without one, "Bob, will you come here?" becomes the confusing "Bob will ...." and the comma seems the natural choice.  Salutations are just vocatives.  Modern typewriters (QWERTY, four-row, visible-type) became popular in the US in the 1890s, so the colon for business correspondence would seem to predate mechanical type.

Comment: another user commented about this in the sense that Latin doesn't have punctuation... So in Latin, Dear Cicero, would be written Dear Cicere (?)...the word form IS the punctuation.  Ok, what about the colon?

Comment: @michael_timofeev No, a salutation in a Latin letter would use the dative case with a verb in the third person, as though the letter (or its deliverer) was speaking, so *Ciceroni salutem dicit* or "To Cicero I say greetings"  Somewhere before 1890, somebody in the US decided that a colon was more formal than a comma and thus more suitable for a business letter.  I'm not sure how to go about tracking down first usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of X as a variable that several different sorts of critter can occupy.

If you want a formal salutation, use a colon or semi-colon.  If you want an informal salutation, use a comma.

I would not write "Dear Bob" with no punctuation at all.

"Dear X" is called a *salutation* or *greeting*.

Comment: I know it is called a salutation but why is that we can use a colon to make it more formal?  Why is comma ok?  What kind of phrase is it that allows so much variation?

Comment: Well, I've seen many a discourse here on ELU about punctuation being a preference thing, not a rule thing.  The custom is that the colon and the semi-colon are more formal, respectful and reserved than the comma.  One is taught those customs of letter writing during one's youth, and the more examples one reads, the more ingrained this becomes.

Comment: I know...I watched my dad write letters when I was a kid and saw the different punctuation.  But was it a random decision at one point to just put a colon and say "This means it's formal."  There must have been some sort of grammar thinking.

Comment: Besides, I don;t see the colon much anymore...what happened to it?  Why is the comma used more?

Comment: I have learned here not to confuse grammar and punctuation.  /  The colon is used a bit less now because some people are sloppy and some people are ignorant.  /  I do still use and see colons and semi-colons in formal letters plenty.

Comment: I ask this, because a student asked me this, and all I could say is "I'm not sure.  Let me find out for you."  May I ask what job you are in?  I teach business correspondence writing to ESL students and it would be good for me to know if this is still widely used...I can't seem to find good answers.

Comment: Teach them to write beautiful letters and use the colon or the semi-colon.  Also tell them that when they are writing to a friend (which they won't need to do for your course), they should use a comma.

Comment: I guess you need to receive letters from insurance companies, etc., more often.  I just got a (very annoying) letter from my son's school yesterday that addressed us as Mr and Ms, with a colon.

Comment: http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/01/greetings_and_s.html, https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/653/01/ ... Still in use.  This is a style issue that has been standardized into a convention.

Comment: @aparente001 Why did the colon annoy you?  Was it because the content of the letter didn't warrant the level of formality of a colon?

Comment: No no.  The letter was very annoying, not the colon.

Comment: @aparente001 When I was a kid, write a letter meant haul out the Underwood or IBM and get some nice paper from dad's drawer.  Now, I'm teaching people in their 20s and 30s who think write a letter is type some words on their iphone...plus they use "Hi" as a salutation for emails to their bosses in America or other countries..."They write like that," is what the say when I ask them.  But they feel confused because their foreign teachers (me) say "do this." and their high school English teacher said "do this."